# Why does changing default file under sites-available also changes the default under sites-enabled in nginx?

Tags: apache, tomcat, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

So, In nginx we have default file under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled as well as /etc/nginx/sites-available. If I make a change in one, it reflects in the other. Why is it so? I don't want to know how to fix this (but answering it would help), but I am mainly looking into why and how does it gets reflected in both the places.

Answer (score 1):

The files in "sites-enabled" are [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from the files in "sites-available". That means they don't have own "content", but **point** to the other files.